# Combining grep and sendmail

Tags: perl, unix

I am looking for a way using the command line in UNIX to email the results from a grep command.

I am grepping the error logs looking for a "searchword". I temporarily want to email the results to my work account. This is a temporary solution until the SA has the time to write a script that will write it to a file where the file will be read by an automated analyzing program.

```
sendmail joetester@workemail.com < grep searchword error*
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do it that they can share. Thank you.

Comment: Separate it out first, might be easier to debug.

Comment: How does one typically pipe output from one script to another?

Comment: I have simplified the grep command to a simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like `grep searchword error* | sendmail joetester@workemail.com`, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/370935/how-to-sendmail-via-command-line-piping).